# Independent t-test for between 2 samples, using function other than Mean

Tags: t-test, inference, mean

I have 2 sample groups of `n = 1000` individuals for each group. Each individual rates the quality of a product on a scale from 1 to 10, and these rating are the entire dataset I am working with. I am simply comparing the ratings between groups.

**First**, I begin by using a simple independent t-test to assess whether there is a statistically significant difference between the means in these two unrelated sample groups.

**Second**, for these particular product ratings, I am also interested in the difference between groups for another function (other than mean), this function being the:

`f(data) = number of times rated as 10 - number of times rated as 6 or lower`

Assume that in the first sample, there were `275 ratings of 10`, and `171 ratings of 6 or lower`, and in the second sample, there were `205 10 ratings of 10`, and `118 ratings of 6 or lower`. Given these values, the results of this new function on each sample is `275 - 171 = 104` for sample 1, and `205 - 118 = 87` for sample 2.

**My question is simply then:** is there a statistical test I can use, to be able to confirm with statistical significance that these function values are different between the 2 samples? I assume I cannot simply use another independent t-test, using the function values and the sample variances of the product ratings, although I am not quite sure.

Let me know if I can clarify any parts of the question. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Likert scores, lots of people pretend to have interval data and test these scores using t tests. Using 'number of 10's minus number of below-7's leaves you with only one number per group of 1000.

Two ideas:

**(1) Chi-squared homogeneity test.** You might admit that the data are fundamentally categorical, make a contingency table with two rows A & B for groups and three columns for `<7`, `7-9` and `10`. Then do a chi-squared test to see if A and B are homogeneous with respect to the three sore categories. If so, look at important differences as guided by large Pearson residuals.

```
TBL = rbind(c(171,554,275), c(118,677,205))
TBL
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  171  554  275
[2,]  118  677  205

out = chisq.test(TBL); out

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 32.218, df = 2, p-value = 1.009e-07
out$resi

          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]  2.204509 -2.478912  2.25924
[2,] -2.204509  2.478912 -2.25924
```

Comparing observed and expected counts, it seems that group A
was more decisive than group B, with substantially fewer `7-9`
scores.

**An *ad hoc* comparison:** Because of the high emphasis many consumer satisfaction experts
put on 'top' Likert scores from surveys, it might be worthwhile
seeing if the proportion of `10`'s differs significantly between the two
groups.

```
prop.test(c(275,205), c(1000,1000), alte="greater")

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(275, 205) out of c(1000, 1000)
X-squared = 13.051, df = 1, p-value = 0.0001516
alternative hypothesis: greater
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0376894 1.0000000
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
 0.275  0.205
```

The sample proportion $0.275$ of `10`s in Group A is
highly significantly greater than the sample proportion
of `10`s in Group B.

**(2) Two-sample tests on transformed scores.** You might transform each individual's score from Likert `1-6`
to $-1$ for `<7`, $0$ for `7-9`, and $1$ for `10`. Then since you have 1000 in each group, you might get something useful from a 2-sample t test on the transformed data.

```
a = rep(c(-1,0,1), c(171,554,275))
b = rep(c(-1,0,1), c(118,677,205))
summary(a); sd(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -1.000   0.000   0.000   0.104   1.000   1.000 
[1] 0.6600149  # SD a
summary(b); sd(b)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -1.000   0.000   0.000   0.087   0.000   1.000 
[1] 0.5619135  # SD b
```

Notice that my transformation to values $-1, 0, 1$ has
given scores to each person that make it possible to
to do a t test on individual subjects.

```
sum(a)
[1] 104  # 275 "10"s minus 118 "below 7"s
sum(b)
[1] 87   # 205 "10"s minus 118 "below 7"s
```

Now we're ready to do a Welch 2-sample t test.

```
t.test(a,b)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

 data:  a and b
 t = 0.62019, df = 1948.4, p-value = 0.5352
 alternative hypothesis: 
    true difference in means is not equal to 0
 95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.03675809  0.07075809
 sample estimates:
 mean of x mean of y 
     0.104     0.087
```

There is no hint that the sample means of the two groups are
significantly different.

The data in `a` and `b` are highly discrete and so hardly
normal, but with a thousand of each there is little doubt
that the sample means used in the t test are very nearly normal.
So I don't doubt the validity of the outcome: failing to reject the null hypothesis.

Traditionally, Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon tests have not worked well
with data that have many ties, but the implementation of this
test in R uses approximations for large samples and does not give an error message about ties.
This test fails to find a difference in the 'locations' of
the transformed data in `a` and `b`. The non-significant P-value of this test is shown below.

```
wilcox.test(a,b)$p.val
[1] 0.3807537
```

In summary, I would not say that the idea to focus on scores of 10 and below 7 is a total failure. The chi-squared test gives a highly significant result and it may be worthwhile doing some additional
*ad hoc* tests comparing various proportions.

However, because your t test with the original Likert data gave
a highly significant result and because a t test with the transformed data does not even reach near significance, I think
it is fair to say that the transformation has resulted in the
loss of some potentially important information.